# JSPdf not loading issue when trying to upload image

Tags: javascript, django, pdf, jspdf

I have created a pdf format using the code snippet below and django is filling this pdf with data. When I try to add images using the code I gave below as an example of this pdf format, the images are not added properly. I want these images to be inserted clearly.

I am attaching the images like this:

```
var logo = document.getElementById("logo").src;
console.log(logo);
doc.addImage(logo, "PNG", 5, 2, 20, 10);
```

pdf size before adding image: 187 KB
after adding : 3.171 KB

How can I add these images here?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I updated again